# How to store a time in iphone preferences

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, settings.bundle

I want to store a time of day value using NSUserDefaults and allow the user to update that through the Settings app. Is there a way to store a NSDate object and tell Settings app to use a time picker only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save date to `NSUserDefaults`. But you cannot add a date picker to settings bundle. There are no options available using this in settings.bundle plist. For more details [please check apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Only options are,

> **Text field:** The text field type displays a title (optional) and an editable text
>   field. You can use this type for preferences that require the user to
>   specify a custom string value. The key for this type is ***PSTextFieldSpecifier***.
>
> **Title:** The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this
>   type to display read-only preference values. (If the preference
>   contains cryptic or nonintuitive values, this type lets you map the
>   possible values to custom strings.) The key for this type is ***PSTitleValueSpecifier***.
>
> **Toggle switch:** The toggle switch type displays an ON/OFF toggle button. You can use
>   this type to configure a preference that can have only one of two
>   values. Although you typically use this type to represent preferences
>   containing Boolean values, you can also use it with preferences
>   containing non-Boolean values. The key for this type is ***PSToggleSwitchSpecifier***.
>
> **Slider:** The slider type displays a slider control. You can use this type for a
>   preference that represents a range of values. The value for this type
>   is a real number whose minimum and maximum value you specify. The key for this type is ***PSSliderSpecifier***.
>
> **Multivalue:** The multivalue type lets the user select one value from a list of
>   values. You can use this type for a preference that supports a set of
>   mutually exclusive values. The values can be of any type. The key for this type is ***PSMultiValueSpecifier***.
>
> **Group:** The group type is for organizing groups of preferences on a single
>   page. The group type does not represent a configurable preference. It
>   simply contains a title string that is displayed immediately before
>   one or more configurable preferences. The key for this type is ***PSGroupSpecifier***.
>
> **Child pane:** The child pane type lets the user navigate to a new page of
>   preferences. You use this type to implement hierarchical preferences.
>   For more information on how you configure and use this preference
>   type, see “Hierarchical Preferences.” The key for this type is ***PSChildPaneSpecifier***.

In order to save date to userdefaults,

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentDate forKey:@"dateKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - more or less what I anticipated.